# MySQLi how to check if table exists?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to create table by app if there's no such table. But doing it for the first time... Need some help, tho

```
 //connecting...
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_params['host'], $db_params['login'],   $db_params['pass'], $db_params['name']);

if ($mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE `products`")){
echo ' YES';
} else echo 'no';
```

It always says NO.

Comment: You're missing a `$` on your `db_params['pass']`

Comment: ofcourse a table 'products' was created in PHP_my_admin

Comment: @Albzi just missed it while typing my question, thx. In real code i have it)

Comment: Try adding `echo $mysqli->error;` and see what MySQL is saying

Comment: You must have a string to the right of `LIKE`  e.g. `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'products'`. In general try your queries in the command-line before writing the corresponding PHP code.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`products`' at line 1

Comment: The MySQL user account connecting might not have permission to execute show tables

Answer (score 6):

Read their documentation? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-features-create-if-not-exists.html Seems like you can do that easily:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products`
```

This way you don't have to check first whether a table exists or not, you just create one if it doesn't.

And it seems like you have a syntax error, which is probably the reason why your code keeps returning "no". This should work:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'products';
```

Just use single or double quotes, no backticks like `` ` ``.

You use backticks (`` ` ``) for table and column names, single (`'`) or double quotes (`"`) for strings, in this case you are giving a string so you should  use single or double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP **DESCRIBE** statement.

```
if(mysql_query("DESCRIBE `table_name`")) {
    // Exists
}
```

Comment: This is `mysql_*`. You should be `mysqli_*` or PDO

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a table if it not exists, you can use

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution works for me JUST FINE:

```
<?php
// connect to the "tests" database
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'tests');

// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
}

// SQL query
$sql = "SHOW TABLES IN `tests`";

// perform the query and store the result
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// if the $result not False, and contains at least one row
if($result !== false) {
  // if at least one table in result
  if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // traverse the $result and output the name of the table(s)
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo '<br />'. $row['Tables_in_tests'];
    }
  }
  else echo 'There is no table in "tests"';
}
else echo 'Unable to check the "tests", error - '. $conn->error;

$conn->close();
?>
```

For a complete and more examples, here the source : http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/check-table-exists-database_t

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18345381)

Comment: @CharlieFish, here is the code, but why the -1 ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote you.

Comment: I think you presented a very bad solution, you have to go through all the tables it's not a clean code that's why people rated you poorly.